# Assigning a value to a PHP global variable to alert

Tags: php, html, variables, alert, global

I am working on a very basic random name generator.  The generator works great, and is called by an HTML form submit button.  Now, in the case that a user wanted to save the name, I will have a second button that will call a PHP mail action to email the name.  Before I add the mail function, I'm just trying to store the variable somewhere so that I can alert it and validate that I have control over it.  In the following code $field2 is the name which is located by $id_num which equals $search_str.  I then try and assign $field2 to the global variable $nameContainer:

```
<body>
<?
$nameContainer = "Mary";
?>

<? 
function loadName() {
global $nameContainer;
if(!empty($_POST['act'])) {
    $lineNum = rand(1, 5189);
    $search_str = $lineNum; 
    $lines = file('names_girls_5189_origin.csv'); 
    foreach($lines as $line){ 
        list($id_num, $field2, $field3, $field4)=explode(",",$line); 
        $nameContainer = ($id_num == $search_str) ? "$field2" : "";
        echo ($id_num == $search_str) ? 
            "<table style= 'height: 100%;'>
            <tr style='width: 100%; height= '200px';'>
            </tr>
            <center><span class='myText' style='color: white; font-size: 48px;'>$field2</span>
            <span style='color: #E8C8D5; font-size: 36px'>Smith</span><br/>
            <span class='myText' style='color: #2E7B4D; font-size: 24px;'>Origin: $field3</span><br/>
            <span class='myText' style='color: #2E7B4D; font-size: 24px;'>Meaning: $field4</span></center>
            </table>" : ""; 
    }
}
}
loadName();

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function alertName() {
    alert("<? getName(); ?>");
}
</script>

<?
function getName() {
global $nameContainer;
echo $nameContainer;
}
?>

<center><form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="act" value="run" />
<p><input type="submit" value="New" /></p>
</form>
</center>

<center><button onclick="alertName()">Alert</button></center>

</body>
```

It appears my problem stems from $nameContainer = ($id_num == $search_str) ? "$field2" : ""; because $nameContainer = $field2; works but assigns the very last name in the csv rather than the one that matches the search string.  I realize there's probably some basic logic I'm missing here, so any help is appreciated!

Update (sample csv):

```
ID,Name,Origin,Meaning
1,Aaliyah,"Arabic, Hebrew","high exalted, to ascend"
2,Akala,Aboriginal,A parrot.
3,Alba,Aboriginal,A sand hill. Also see Albina.
5188,Zelma,,A divine helmet. From the name Anselma. Also see Salima.
5189,Zola,,Life.`
```

Comment: Right before the $nameContainer line can you paste the results of: `echo "id_num: ".$id_num." search_str: ".$search_str;` Also, why is the $field2 in quotes on that line?

Comment: Are you sure that the first data on each line is a number and that these numbers are filling the interval [1,5189]?

Comment: @Lewyx Yeah, I compiled the csv myself.  First column is populated with ID numbers, followed by the name, origin, and meaning, like the updated OP.  The number starts at 1 to exclude the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need to check if `$nameContainer` has content and break the loop:

```
$nameContainer = ($id_num == $search_str) ? "$field2" : "";
if(!empty($nameContainer)){
    break;
}
```

But, to make it work, you need to initialize `$nameContainer` with empty string:

```
$nameContainer = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're using `$search_str` to pick a line (an element of the `$lines` array) at random. You should use [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) for this:

```
function loadName() {
global $nameContainer;
if(!empty($_POST['act'])) {
    list($id_num, $field2, $field3, $field4)=explode(",",array_rand(file('names_girls_5189_origin.csv'))); 
    $nameContainer = $field2;
    echo "<table style= 'height: 100%;'>...</table>" : ""; 
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, at least as you have it formatted, this doesn't work.  I still get nothing in my alert (i.e. a value is not assigned to `$nameContainer`), but then values are never assigned to the variables `$id_num`, `$field2`, etc. in the list, either.  If I simplify the code down to your `array_rand` function as above, and then just echo the four variables in the list, the page comes back blank.